# Why dd output file is bigger then the original input

Tags: clone, dd

If I clone a disk to disk like this:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
```

The second disk will contain the data of the first disk without any space issue, but when I create an image of `/dev/sda`, say it has capacity of 10GB, the result file will be in my case ~48GB. Now my question is why cloned disk to image has a bigger length, while cloned disk to disk having same capacity won't produce space issue?

Comment: Same problem, but only when using the "conv=noerror,sync" options.